# Couldnt launch JEM.jar Jython Music

Tags: jython-music

I'm getting error: the java jar file JEM.jar could not be launched when opening on a Mac OSX Machine. Any idea how to resolve this and get #JythonMusic running. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install [Java version 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Also, if you have Java 9 installed, [uninstall it](https://gist.github.com/schnell18/bcb9833f725be22f6acd01f94b486392).

You need Java 8, since [Java 9 breaks Jython](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2630)...

Answer (score 1):

after installing java 8, python2.7.18, and jython2.7.3, download and  unzip jythonmusic https://jythonmusic.me/download/ , then drag JEM.jar onto desktop or applications. I dragged the jythonMusic folder into 'mydocuments'. it then seems to run without errors. instructions are not clear given that its meant to be for beginners